# Incremental/Partial Deployment using SalesforceDX

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, sfdc, sfdc-migration-tool

Is there any way to make Incremental/Partial Deployment using SalesforceDX. So that only the components that are changed are deployed, instead of a full build?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying to a scratch org, unfortunately you can only push all changes that have been made locally to the org.

However, if you are deploying to a Dev Hub org, you can right click on the component's folder and click "Deploy Source to Org"

[deploying source to org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdPae.png)

Comment: Do you have steps to automate this in Jenkins CI tool or using script?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't tell you anything about this automation since I haven't really explored it.

Comment: Hey @Emmanuel Ngenoh ! No worries , I found a command working   "git diff previous-commit-id latest-commit-id | force-dev-tool changeset create vat"

Thanks to Roman answered in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184332/is-there-a-pre-build-solution-for-generating-a-package-xml-from-a-git-repo

Answer (score 0):

You can also decide which files you would like to deploy using coma separated list like this:

sfdx force:source:deploy -p path/file1, path/file2, …

Comment: How to create incremental package.xml? I want to automatic process for my CI (Jenkins). Hope package.xml is needed for sfdx deployment if not interested to use a custom command like using -p option in your command.